# NativeXml and  threading

Tags: xml, delphi, nativexml

I am tryng to get this library working with thread but I am not able to get result back to the main thread using syncronize.

No problem creating xml within excute method.

Someone have used it?

- [NativeXml](http://www.simdesign.nl/xml.htm)

---

```
   TMyThread = class(TThread)
       private
       ADoc : TNativeXml;
        protected
         procedure Execute; override;
         procedure DoProgress;
       public
         constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
      end;

    { TMyThread }

    constructor TMyThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
    begin
      inherited;
    end;

procedure TMyThread.DoProgress;
begin
 formMain.meminfo.Lines.Add(ADoc.WriteToString);
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var i,j : integer;
begin
  inherited;
begin
    ADoc:= ADoc.Create(formMain);
    try
    Adoc.XmlFormat := xfReadable;
    ADoc.LoadFromFile('test.xml');
    Synchronize(DoProgress);
    finally 
       FreeAndNil(ADoc);
    end;
end;
end;
```

Comment: What happens when you run this?  Exception? Nothing? Empty string?  Debugger crash?  Please provide more info.

Answer (score 8):

Not getting the result back to the main thread or getting access violation at this line?

```
ADoc:= ADoc.Create(formMain);
```

That single line of code contains one bug and one [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell): The code smell is that you're reffering to `formMain`, from a thread. The bug is that you're not calling `.Create()` on a class name but on the variable name itself! You probably wanted:

```
ADoc := TNativeXml.Create(nil);
```

Comment: I agree! My suspicion is that the thread is terminating at the very first line (with possibly a hidden exception).
Breakpoints on the first, third and second-to-last lines of the Execute procedure would quickly determine if it is raising a hidden exception. Either way... I absolutely agree that the call to .Create is incorrect!

Comment: Ops , sorry guys . Yes it's wrong. Will change and test it again.

Comment: @marcostT if it works, you should mark Cosmin's answer as correct :)